# PostgreSQL timezone setting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

While I've spent many years as a SQL developer, I'm not really a DBA, but I'm the closest thing that my company has to one. We have recently started moving many of our PostgreSQL databases from Heroku to our own Digital Ocean servers. One of the differences that I recently noticed was that all of the Heroku datbases' timezone setting are configured to 'UTC', and all of our Digital Ocean databases are set to 'localtime'.

What is best practice here? I've done some 'Googling', but can't really find a clear cut answer.  Is there an advantage to configuring them all to be UTC?

We are using PostgreSQL 9.4 on Ubunut 14.04 servers.

Comment: UTC is generally regarded as ideal since it is not subject to daylight savings and reduces confusion when working with multiple time zones. This may not be an issue depending on your use case.